# Finding an item in a JSON object array with some values and replace if existing

Tags: jquery, angular

I have an array like this which is ofcourse dynamic and each of the element get pushed when clicking an add button next to few form fields

```
[{"EbudgetId":0,"CrId":0,"TypeId":"8","TypeName":"AUGMENT_STAFF","Year":2020,"Cost":456},
{"EbudgetId":0,"CrId":0,"TypeId":"8","TypeName":"AUGMENT_STAFF","Year":2020,"Cost":456},
{"EbudgetId":0,"CrId":0,"TypeId":"8","TypeName":"AUGMENT_STAFF","Year":2020,"Cost":456},
{"EbudgetId":0,"CrId":0,"TypeId":"8","TypeName":"AUGMENT_STAFF","Year":2021,"Cost":657}]
```

What my requirement is if there an Item which of a specific type and year already exists, then it should add with its value rather than pushing into the array.

With that intention I did like this but it doest work

```
  addExternalBudget() {
    
    let typeId:Number  = this.selectedExternalBudget.TypeId;
    let yr:number=this.selectedExternalBudget.Year;
    
    if(typeId==0 || yr==0) return false;

    let ebCopy: ExternalBudget = Object.assign({}, this.selectedExternalBudget);

    
    let existingBudget:ExternalBudget=this.myChangeRequest.NewExternalBudget.find(x=>{x.TypeId===typeId;x.Year==yr});
    if(existingBudget=== undefined){
      this.myChangeRequest.NewExternalBudget.push(ebCopy);
    }
    else
    {
      existingBudget.Cost=this.selectedExternalBudget.Cost+existingBudget.Cost;
    }
    
  }
```

here even when the item already exists with given typeid and year, it getting added as a new item into the array.

What I did wrong here?

I am working in  Angular 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is how your function `addExternalBudget` should look like. Your `find` method is incorrect, inner expression should not have curly braces. If it has curly braces, you will have to return the value explicitly  -

```
addExternalBudget() {
    
    let typeId:Number  = this.selectedExternalBudget.TypeId;
    let yr:number=this.selectedExternalBudget.Year;
    
    if(typeId==0 || yr==0) return false;

    let ebCopy: ExternalBudget = Object.assign({}, this.selectedExternalBudget);

    
    let existingBudget:ExternalBudget=this.myChangeRequest.NewExternalBudget.find(x=> x.TypeId===typeId && x.Year==yr);
    if(!existingBudget){
      this.myChangeRequest.NewExternalBudget.push(ebCopy);
    }
    else
    {
      existingBudget.Cost=this.selectedExternalBudget.Cost+existingBudget.Cost;
    }
    
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your find. You can use `filter` like this to get the matched items:

```js
let foundItems = this.myChangeRequest.NewExternalBudget.filter( _ => (_.TypeId == typeId && _.Year == yr))
```

So, here you get an `array` of matched object that if its `length > 0` you got some answers. So keep processing on `foundItems` .